# Why every time uploaded file count is one for this HttpFileCollection?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, radupload

Though i am not uploading any file it is giving file count one.
Please let me know where i am wrong.

i am doing this for radupload telerik control

actually the radupload count throws always 0

```
RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count
```

that is why i had to implement the following solution

```
 HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
        if (hfc.Count == 0)
        {
            errMessage = "Please upload a file ";
        }

 <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" InitialFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileInputsCount="1"
                    Localization-Select="Browse" runat="server" TargetFolder="~/SlideImages" InputSize="42"
                    OverwriteExistingFiles="True" Skin="Office2010Silver" controlobjectsvisibility="None" MaxFileSize="1000">
                </telerik:RadUpload>
```